# Squared L2 optimization with sum of the vector's elements of 1

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Let $x$ be an $n$-dimensional vector with sum of its elements being $1$: 
$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i=1$$
How can the squared L2 norm of $x$ be optimized? I believe the solution is $\forall i\ \ x_i=\frac{1}{n}$, but I do not follow how to. prove this is optimal formally

Comment: Use the [QM-AM inequality](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Root-Mean_Square-Arithmetic_Mean-Geometric_Mean-Harmonic_mean_Inequality)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem at hand is $\inf_{\mathbf{1}^\top x = 1} x^\top x$, where $\mathbf{1}$ is the $n$-vector of all ones. The Lagrangian associated with this problem is
\begin{equation*}
L(x,\nu) = x^\top x + \nu(\mathbf{1}^\top x - 1).
\end{equation*}
This is a convex quadratic in $x$, and therefore minimizing $L$ over $x$ is equivalent to solving
\begin{equation*}
\nabla_x L(x^*,\nu) = 2x^* + \nu\mathbf{1} = 0.
\end{equation*}
Hence, $x^* = -\frac{\nu}{2}\mathbf{1}$, and therefore the dual function is
\begin{equation*}
g(\nu) = \inf_{x\in\mathbb{R}^n}L(x,\nu) = L(x^*,\nu) = \frac{\nu^2}{4}\mathbf{1}^\top\mathbf{1} + \nu (-\frac{\nu}{2}\mathbf{1}^\top\mathbf{1} - 1) = -\frac{n \nu^2}{4} - \nu.
\end{equation*}
This is a concave quadratic in $\nu$, and therefore we can maximize $g$ by setting its derivative to zero:
\begin{equation*}
g'(\nu^*) = -\frac{n}{2}\nu^* - 1 = 0,
\end{equation*}
or equivalently, $\nu^* = -\frac{2}{n}$. Substituting this result back into the optimal primal, $x^*$, yields
\begin{equation*}
x^* = \frac{1}{n}\mathbf{1},
\end{equation*}
as you expected.